# Consultas con My SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Tengo una consulta SQL sin poder resolver:

Estructura de las tablas usadas:

> Tabla usuario

```
id pk uq ai nn
nombre varchar(25) null
apellido varchar(25) null
```

> Tabla posicion

```
id pk uq ai nn
cargo varchar(50) null
departamento varchar(50) null
```

> Tabla usuario_posicion

```
id pk uq ai nn
us_id fk -> usuario.id nn
pos_id fk -> posicion.id nn
```

La idea es tomar desde una consulta todos los datos que tenga en usuario_posicion a través de sus respectivos id.
Se me complica mucho el inner join:

```
SELECT usuario.nombre, usuario.apellido, posicion.cargo, posicion.departamento 
FROM usuario, posicion 
INNER join usuario_posicion 
ON ((usuario.id = usuario_posicion.us_id) AND (posicion.id = usuario_posicion.pos_id ))
WHERE {aca evalúo una dupla nombre_de_usuario/contraseña que también está en la tabla usuario}
```

MySQL me ha devuelto una serie de errores debido al embrollo que estoy haciendo:

1) "La columna usuario.id en on clause es desconocida" (con la consulta anteriormente mencionada)

2) "Tabla/Alias es no unico" (con una consulta similar en la que había cambiado el orden de las tablas a operar con join )

**Nota**: Se que es un inconveniente a la hora de pensarlo (me estoy haciendo un lío bárbaro para ser franco).
Agradezco explicaciones, comentarios y más siempre que aporten :). Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con lo siguiente:

```
 SELECT usuario.nombre, usuario.apellido, posicion.cargo, 
 posicion.departamento 
 FROM usuario inner join usuario_posicion on usuario.id = 
 usuario_posicion.us_id
 inner join posicion on posicion.id = usuario_posicion.pos_id 
 WHERE usuario.nombre like 'aquivaelnombreusuario';
```

En la tabla 'usuario_posicion' no es necesario que tengas una llave primaria ya que es una tabla de relacion por lo que te recomiendo eliminar la columna 'id', comenta si te ha servido

Comment: Gracias por tu pronta respuesta. Recién pude verificar el código, entenderlo y luego ejecuté la consulta con éxito. Sólo cambié el operador 'like' por '=' pero no va al caso, la consulta en sí funciona, te agradezco enormemente :).

Comment: Es recomendable utilizar la palabra reservada 'Like' en lugar de utilizar el signo '=' (por cuestiones de seguridad y rendimiento) para comparar cadenas, para que lo tomes en cuenta